# Reading a directory and listing the files it contains

Tags: php, directory

I need to write the class in PHP. Input takes the path (directory name). The class has two methods:

1. files - returns an array of file names of this directory.
2. table - returns a generated html table with a list of files in this directory.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please try to learn the basics in PHP OOPs...

Comment: What is sgererirovanuyu  table?

Comment: We are helping here, not coding for someone. Tell what's the problem and we'll try to help.

Comment: I've fixed the title to reflect the question, but I'm totally not touching "sgererirovanuyu."

Answer (score 3):

You *don't* need to create a class for this.  In fact, you *should not*.  That is overly complex and entirely unnecessary.

If you need to read the list of files in a directory, you have three options: [`readdir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php), [`glob`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), or  [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php).

If you need to read the list of files in a directory, and all the directories inside of it, then you want to use [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).

There are adequate usage examples on the linked documentation pages.

Using these, you can get your list'o'files and build your HTML.

Comment: I agree with everything but the first statement. There isn't necessarily any reason not to create a method (either class or function) that wraps up this functionality so it can be replicated in different locations more easily and consistently.

Comment: Classes are designed to contain and encapsulate complexity.  I could see a *function* that produces the HTML output, but really, seriously now, a class?  PHP ain't Java.  Considering that the OP *doesn't seem to know* how to perform the basic task of getting a list of files in a directory, I highly doubt that a *class* is going to be the thing he actually needs in order to accomplish the goal.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not; I'm not sure what they do/don't know. I just don't agree with saying they "should not" because it's "overly complex and completely unnecessary". Maybe a function could be a better overall choice, I just think that's a choice for the OP to make.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple example of class.

```
class MyFiles {

    public static function files($path) {
        // Logic used to get the files found at path and return an array
        // Just use the built-in functionality of PHP
        $filesArray = array();

        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            return $filesArray;
        }

        $dir  = opendir($path);
        while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dir))) {
            if (!is_dir($filename)) {
                $filesArray[] = $filename;
            }
        }

        return $filesArray;
    }

    public static function table($path) {
        $files = self::files($path);
        $c_files = count($files);

        if ($c_files == 0) {
            return "<table><tbody><tr><td>No files at $path</td></tr></tbody></table>";
        }

        $table = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $c_files; $i++) {
            $table .= "<tr><td>{$files[$i]}</td></tr>";
        }

        return "<table><tbody>$table</tbody></table>";
    }

}

$fileTable = MyFiles::table('/my/path/with/files');
```

Comment: `<pedantic>` You forgot the `<tbody>`, and should probably use `self::` inside the `table` method instead of the class name.  +1 for example code anyway. `</pedantic>`

Comment: Yeah, I know; I considered putting tbody in but decided I could be lazy on that point. Why would self be better when calling internally?

Comment: `class YourFiles extends MyFiles { public static files($path) { return array("TOTALLY DIFFERENT"); } }`  -- calling `YourFiles::table($path)` is going to end up with a call to `MyFiles::files` instead of `YourFiles::files`.  Using `self` will ensure that the class name is resolved properly.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I figured that out pretty much right after I posted the comment and saw GolezTrol's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is good to create a class for such functionaliteit, because you can much better predict its behaviour and work around subtle changes in PHP over different versions. Also, you can create different classes to read lists of files from other locations like a database or csv file.

In this case, I extended a renderer class from the base class, because I figured the rendering shouldn't be part of the base class. In fact, it might be better to create a separate class for this that uses any descendant of Folder to render it. But I'll leave it to you to figure out what suits you best.

```
<?
class Folder
{
    private $folder = '';
    public function getFolder()
    {
        return $this->folder;
    }
    protected function setFolder($value)
    {
        $this->folder = (string)$folder;
    }

    public __construct($folder)
    {
        this->setFolder($folder);
    }

    public function readFileNames()
    {
        $folder = (string)$this->getFolder();
        if ($folder === '')
        {
            throw new exception("Folder name is empty");
        }
        if (is_dir($folder) !== true)
        {
            throw new exception("'$folder' is not a directory.");
        }
        $dir = @opendir($this->folder);
        if ($dir === false)
        {
            throw new exception("Cannot open directory '$folder'.");
        }
        $result = array();
        while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($dir)))
        {
            if (is_file($fileName) === true)
            {
                $result[] = $fileName;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function readFiles()
    {
        $fileNames = $this->readFileNames();
        $fileNames = array_flip($fileNames);
        foreach($fileNames as $fileName=>&$fileContents)
        {
            if (false === ($file = @readFile($fileName)))
            {
                $fileContents = null;
            }
            else
            {
                $fileContents = $file;
            }
        }
    }
}

class FolderTableRenderer extends Folder
{
    public function renderTable()
    {
?>
    <table>
        <thead><tr><th>File name</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
<?
        foreach ($this->readFileNames() as $fileName)
        {
?>
            <tr><td><?=$fileName?></td></tr>
<?
        }
?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?
    }
}
```